# Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Command 'npm install' failed to finish for Sparing Boot app with Vaadin

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14, pnpm

I have a Spring Boot stub project just generated on Spring Initializr, with pnpm preinstalled, but currenty no `npm` is installed, runned on Windows 10 with `mvn spring-boot:run`

The pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>tatar.gis</groupId>
    <artifactId>geodata</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>geodata</name>
    <description>Geodata Manipulation project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.8.1</vaadin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

And the console output is:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.2:run (default-cli) @ geodata ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.2)
2022-01-07 18:39:54.874  INFO 16476 --- [           main] tatar.gis.geodata.GeodataApplication     : Starting GeodataApplication using Java 1.8.0_65 on ILYA with PID 16476 (D:\Java\geodata\target\classes started by eljah32 in D:\Java\geodata)
2022-01-07 18:39:54.876  INFO 16476 --- [           main] tatar.gis.geodata.GeodataApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-01-07 18:39:55.815  INFO 16476 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-01-07 18:39:55.823  INFO 16476 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-01-07 18:39:55.823  INFO 16476 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-01-07 18:39:55.919  INFO 16476 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-01-07 18:39:55.919  INFO 16476 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1009 ms
2022-01-07 18:39:57.974  INFO 16476 --- [           main] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for subclasses and classes with annotations took 1 seconds
2022-01-07 18:39:57.975  INFO 16476 --- [           main] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Due to slow search it is recommended to use the whitelisted-packages feature to make scanning faster.
See the whitelisted-packages section in the docs at https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/integrations/spring/configuration#special-configuration-parameters
2022-01-07 18:39:57.978  INFO 16476 --- [           main] c.v.f.server.startup.DevModeInitializer  : Starting dev-mode updaters in D:\Java\geodata folder.
2022-01-07 18:39:58.006  INFO 16476 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Visited 90 classes. Took 20 ms.
2022-01-07 18:39:58.017  INFO 16476 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Added 23 default dependencies to main package.json
2022-01-07 18:39:58.038  INFO 16476 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Running `npm install` to resolve and optionally download frontend dependencies. This may take a moment, please stand by...
2022-01-07 18:39:58.210 ERROR 16476 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Error when running `npm install`
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "--no-update-notifier" (in directory "D:\Java\geodata"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmInstall(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:365) [flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.execute(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:138) [flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:529) [flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DevModeInitializer.initDevModeHandler(DevModeInitializer.java:330) [flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:447) [vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:180) [vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:180) [vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:473) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:206) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at tatar.gis.geodata.GeodataApplication.main(GeodataApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
2022-01-07 18:39:58.211 ERROR 16476 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize Vaadin DevModeHandler
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:450) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.lambda$contextInitialized$0(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:180) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$CompositeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:180) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:473) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:206) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) [spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at tatar.gis.geodata.GeodataApplication.main(GeodataApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Command 'npm install' failed to finish
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DevModeInitializer.initDevModeHandler(DevModeInitializer.java:341) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.VaadinServletContextInitializer$DevModeServletContextListener.contextInitialized(VaadinServletContextInitializer.java:447) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Command 'npm install' failed to finish
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmInstall(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:409) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.execute(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:138) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:529) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.DevModeInitializer.initDevModeHandler(DevModeInitializer.java:330) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "--no-update-notifier" (in directory "D:\Java\geodata"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunNpmInstall.runNpmInstall(TaskRunNpmInstall.java:365) ~[flow-server-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
2022-01-07 18:39:58.212 ERROR 16476 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2022-01-07 18:39:58.212 ERROR 16476 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2022-01-07 18:39:58.494  INFO 16476 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-01-07 18:39:58.497  WARN 16476 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2022-01-07 18:39:58.504  INFO 16476 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-01-07 18:39:58.523 ERROR 16476 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) [spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at tatar.gis.geodata.GeodataApplication.main(GeodataApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:473) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:206) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vaadin plugin is missing in the build section.

Add this plugin in build -> plugins

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The easiest way to create a Vaadin project ist https://start.vaadin.com

Comment: Currently, before adding the frontend plugin, I have completed with system node.js and npm installation and restarted the IDE to make it's console to re-read the env variables. So now the start process loads the npm dependencies

Comment: `2022-01-07 19:16:53.592  INFO 8252 --- [           main] c.v.f.server.startup.DevModeInitializer  : Starting dev-mode updaters in D:\Java\geodata folder.
2022-01-07 19:16:53.611  INFO 8252 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Visited 90 classes. Took 15 ms.
2022-01-07 19:16:53.640  INFO 8252 --- [           main] dev-updater                              : Running npm install to resolve and optionally download frontend dependencies. This may take a moment, please stand by...`

Comment: @IlyaYevlampiev That log looks good. Did it work?

Comment: You don't have to run anything by your own.

Comment: Not it is good. In fact pom xml already had the needed frontend plugin, but execution env un the ide terminal knowed nothing about already but just installed npm utility and reference to it un PATH system variable

Answer (score 3):

I recently reproduced this problem on Windows 10, node-v16.16.0-x64.msi, vaadin 14.6.8.

After some investigations in Vaadin code, I found the problem in class FrontendTools: -> tryLocateTool -> verifyTool -> omitErrorResult.

The problem is this - npm writes a warning in stderr:

```
npm -version
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
8.11.0
```

On Vaadin side, FrontendTools.omitErrorResult checks if stderr is empty (and for this version it is not, so npm command is not used).

One quick solution for Vaadin is to also check if stderr does not contain "npm WARN".

Until the fix is done in Vaadin, the quick solution is found here:

[Message "npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/message-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-loc)

I used the solution for windows (thanks to @ZiiMakc and @Lars) :

Open PowerShell as administrator and run (info about policy):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version latest
```

The result now:

```
npm -version
8.13.2
```